# FancyUpload - Replace Flash

Tags: flash, file-upload, fancyupload

I have been using FancyUpload for quite some time. It seems that I now need to replace the flash portion since Chrome will be stopping flash soon.

I know that there are other uploaders out there, but I am hoping that there might be an easy solution for me to continue to use FancyUpload.

It seems to just be a matter of replacing the .swf file(This is the Flash file extension) with a different file that doesn't require flash to be downloaded.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!!